# I don't know what might be causing a redirect response in Rails app

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to render a file to support [Apple Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), which means basically rendering a very small JSON file.

One of the requisites in Apple's website is to serve the file without redirects. But for some reason this project I'm working on has an automatic redirect from `website.com/path` to `www.website.com/path` **in production only**. I'm not sure if this was intentional and configured this way or if this error lives outside Rails scope (DNS config maybe?).

The Rails (4.1.x) app has the following Router entry:

```
# Router
get '/.well-known/apple-app-site-association', to: 'static_pages#universal_links'
```

And controller function declaration:

```
def universal_links
  file = File.join(Rails.root, 'app/views/static_pages/apple-app-site-association')
  send_file file, disposition: 'inline', type: 'application/json'
end
```

Now, the following requests appear to work properly:

- **DEVELOPMENT**: `curl localhost:3000/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`
- **PRODUCTION**: `curl www.website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`
- **PRODUCTION**: `curl https://www.website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

But these requests are **not working**:

- **PRODUCTION**: `curl website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`
- **PRODUCTION**: `curl https://website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

They (both) respond with the redirect:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.website.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

I'm not sure about this being the only reason why the Universal links are not working properly, but I need to understand what is causing this app to redirect (and maybe a way to customize this behavior).

**Note:** From the [Apple's validation tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/) I'm getting the following information:
[image: validation tool fail]

Comment: Are you getting redirected from http to https or vice versa? A production-only redirect could likely be an SSL redirect.

Comment: @chrismanderson Yes, it works for `curl https://www.website.com/...` but not for `curl https://website.com/...`. SSL works fine but I don't know which URL is Apple using to fetch the asset, it might be an issue if they only fetch bare domains (without `www` prefix). I'm not sure if such a redirect is possible using Rails configuration (I inherited this codebase and don't know very well exactly what to look for). I just updated the question to include this.

Comment: This may indeed be a DNS configuration issue. Can you post your DNS config, at least the `A` and `CNAME` records?

Comment: Follow Borama's instruction.  99% sure that's what you need.